# android datepicker

Tags: android, дата

Народ подскажите как изменить внешний вид DatePicker у меня по умолчанию показывается год в виде недель.
Как установить год простой прокруткой вверх и вниз?
[image: изображение datepicker]

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал использовать вот эту библиотеку https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers , ну какой смысл пихать этот унылый пикер дефолтный в приложение, если можно взять и встроить calendarDatePickerDialog в стиле материал как в новых приложениях от гугл.

Answer (score 1):

Вот собственно и ответ

```
datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```